# Rails Craiglist like list of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a state model and city model associated with has_many and belongs_to. I want to display a page with each state with its associated cities underneath.

I created a page controller and page called "Locations" and manually entered in

```
<%= link_to "Allentown", allentown_path %>
```

which then takes you to the allentown page.

On the allentown page I filtered the listings by adding this code to the pages controller

```
def allentown
  @title = "Allentown Listings"
  @tattoo_briefs = TattooBrief.where( :city_id => 1 ).find(:all, :order => "id DESC" )
end
```

I know this isn't DRY. Also can get very cumberson if I have 200 cities.  Is there a better way?

Comment: oh and by the way, it helps to accept some of the answers to your questions if you want people to answer you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a resource to your routes:

routes.rb

```
resources :city
```

That essentially gives you all the RESTful actions for the City model. Then, in your controller, use the **show** action to..wait for it..show your city page

cities_controller.rb

```
def show
  @city = City.find(params[:id])
  @title = "#{@city.name} Listings"
  @tattoo_briefs = TattooBrief.where( :city_id => params[:id] ).find(:all, :order => "id DESC" )
end
```

you can still modify this by studying more on routes and controllers from the rails api. With added knowledge, you can get to allentown by modifying your route to use the city name instead of the id.